# move windows to another non-empty hard disk

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, clone

I have a failing hard disk which has Windows installed.  However, it is still able to copy files.  I have another hard disk, which is not empty and I don't want to format it.

Is it possible to move the Windows installation, to the other hard disk without having to re-install Windows? There is ample space on the new hard disk as its a 1TB hard disk.

OS is Windows 7 SP1

Comment: If you haven't thought of this already you might want to copy everything you don't want to lose off the hard drive first, it may only be possible to copy files for a limited amount of time before the drive dies completely.

Comment: @Richard I have a backup, so no worries about that.  It has several programs installed and configuration, and would like not having to go through that process again by re-installing the OS.  Is it possible?

Comment: If it was me I'd just re-install as I wouldn't have confidence that all of the files on the failing disk were uncorrupted. There are disk cloning tools although you may need to convince the system to boot using the new disk. Sorry I can't be more help!

Comment: Create a parition on the second disk the same size as your system disk.  Create an image of the system disk and restore the image to the disk.  The parition will need to be at the start of the disk for this process to work.  You also will have to move the data off the drive ( for the time being ) for this process to work.  A second data partition can be made after you know the system partition boots.

Comment: You can try doing a dd_rescue to an image and then restoring that image to a new partition on the good disk.

Answer (score -1):

You can try [creating restore disk](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/create-a-restore-point).

To create a restore point

```
Open System by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, right-clicking Computer, and then clicking Properties.

In the left pane, click System protection. Administrator permission required If you're prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.

Click the System Protection tab, and then click Create.

In the System Protection dialog box, type a description, and then click Create.
```

then copy that restore disk to your hard disk.
If you again want to install this just burn it in DVD and you can again restore to that.

Comment: You need to provide a little more detail at least and not just a mere link. Not to mention you linked to a page that discusses how to create a restore point. Mind explaining how exactly System Restore will help in this situation? Also, lmgtfy links aren't acceptable (not to mention rude). People come here *from* Google and other search engines looking for answers.

Comment: Sorry for this, i am new here.
I will follow it in my further actions.